# A RandomForest in a Pipeline - sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

If I create a `Pipeline` in sklearn where the first step is a transformation (`Imputer`) and the second step is fitting a RandomForestClassifier with the keyword argument `warmstart` marked as `True`, how do I successively call the RandomForestClassifier? Does `warmstart` do anything when *embedded* in a `Pipeline?

http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/missing_values.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can, but then the pipeline parts become slightly complex.

You see `warm_start` is only useful if you increase the `n_estimators` in the `RandomForestClassifier`.

[See here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L302):-

```
warn("Warm-start fitting without increasing n_estimators does not fit new trees.")
```

So you will need to increase the `n_estimators` of the `RandomForestClassifier` inside the pipeline.

For that you will first need to access the `RandomForestClassifier` estimator from the pipeline and then set the `n_estimators` as required. But then when you call `fit()` on pipeline, the `imputer` step will still get executed (which just repeats each time).

For example, consider the below pipeline:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('imputer', Imputer()), 
                 ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(warm_start=True))])
```

Now according to your question, you will need to do this to use the `warm_start`:-

```
# Fit the data initially
pipe.fit(X, y)

# Change the n_estimators (any one line from given two)
pipe.set_params(clf__n_estimators=30)
  OR
pipe.named_steps['clf'].n_estimators = 30

# Fit the same data again or new data
pipe.fit(X_new, y_new)
```

In the first call to `pipe.fit()`, the imputer will be fitted on given data (X, y). Now in the second call to `fit()`, two things may happen based on the data:

- If you give same data again, then the imputer will still be fitted again, which is not needed.
- If the data is different, the imputer will be fitted on the new data and forget the previously learnt information. So the imputing of missing values in this new data will be different from how it handled the previous data. This is not what you want in my opinion.

Comment: So this sounds like a pipeline is not really needed for this use case... thanks!